# How to correctly create a transition from a phrase to an unintelligible scream?

Tags: vowels, phrasing, sounds, literary-device

I'm trying to create a transition effect in a situation when a character suddenly finds himself falling, and his last word, which ends in '-y', is transitioning into an unintelligible scream.

However, English is not my native language, and when I've tried to write it as 'Maryeeee!!' it was criticized as awkward and weird. At the same time, the counter-suggestion of simply extending the '-y' at the end and writing 'Maryyyyy!' doesn't feel right to me. It may be grammatically correct, but my goal was to create an impression of a word seamlessly transitioning into a scream, preferably making it clear that it is an unintelligible scream and not just the character's speech trailing off, and if the resulting word would be a horrible mess, it was fine for as long as I achieved the desired effect.

So the question is, how should I go about it?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with "Maryeee!". Surely it's _meant_ to sound weird?

Comment: There will not be a standard way of doing this.

Comment: Can you give more details? Do you actually need to do this with repeated vowels or can you use the dialog tags ("... he screamed.")? I think this may be covered by one of the following: [When writing, should I describe a scream instead of having the character yell out "Ahhhh!"](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/60853/34330) and [How do I write a shriek?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/37055/34330) (and if not, explain the difference, since I'm thinking of migrating your question).

Comment: There's lots of different types of screams, representable as aaargghhh! aiiiiii! owwwwww! eeeuuugghhhh! ooooooohhhh! etc.

Comment: If you're writing some kind of story, you can say what's happening, so you don't have to rely on the reader understanding what Maryeeeee! means, and once they've explicitly been told something like " so-and-so's voice rose to a scream, "Maryeeeee!" you're good to go.

Comment: This should be on Writing. It's about spelling, not English.

Comment: @KateBunting It's meant to sound natural for the situation, so if it breaks the SOD I'd rather change it.

Comment: @Laurel In this case I'm trying to do with speech rather than descriptive text. And migrating is ok if it's not a match for the community.

Comment: FWIW, Mary is accented on the first syllable, Marie on the second.So there's a slight hiatus with Mary, and that name doesn't transition to a scream as smoothly as Marie does.

Comment: This may be a better question for [writing.se].